# Boolean bitwise and logical operators

Tags: c++, operators, bitwise-operators

I Have two `booleans` with `OR` operation between them.

According to my understanding, I can use `bitwise` or `logical` operators and it will have the same effect:

bitwise:

```
bool first = true, second = false;
first = first | second;
```

logical:

```
bool first = true, second = false;
first = first || second;
```

Is there any difference?
What's the better way?

Comment: Use logical or when doing logic.  Use bitwise or when doing bitwise operations.  Don't try and outsmart the compiler.  It will optimize easy to understand code for you.

Comment: The _logical or_ will short-circuit; the _bitwise or_ won't.

Comment: @paolo What do you mean by short circuit?

Comment: If the first operand of `||` evaluates to `true`, the second won't be evaluated. You may read more [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

Comment: That sounds good @paolo, could you please write it as an answer?

Comment: The you're working with Boolean values there is no good reason to pretend that they are bitsets. That's a Java thing, because, well, Java...

Comment: In an earlier ancestor of the language, there was only `|` and `&`.  There were enough problems with that approach that `||` and `&&` was added to distinguish between bitwise and logic operations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in the comments, you should use logical operators when you're doing logic and bitwise operators when doing bitwise operations.

One of the main differences among these is that C++ will [short-circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) the logical operations; meaning that it will stop evaluating the operands as soon as it's clear what the result of the operation is.

As an example, this code:

```cpp
bool foo() {
    std::puts("foo");
    return true;
}

bool bar() {
    std::puts("bar");
    return true;
}

//...

auto const res = foo() || bar();
```

will only output:

```
foo
```

Function `bar` won't be evaluated as, in this case, evaluating `foo` is enough to know the result of expression `foo() || bar()` is `true`.

Comment: I once used explicitly bit-wise operations for functions returning `bool` to prevent the short-circuiting. The functions had side-effects which I intended to get regardless of their returned values. So, the choice of logical vs. bitwise operators should be done with this in mind, even for booleans, IMHO.

Comment: @Scheff'sCat In such situations, I usually store the result of each function in a separate variable and then perform the logic operation on them, once I evaluate everyting; 
e.g.: `auto const fooRes = foo(); auto const barRes = bar(); return fooRes || barRes;` I know it's a matter of taste but I find it clearer.

Comment: Maybe, you're right. `bool`s and bitwise operators look like a typo which might be "corrected" by somebody else. Of course, I didn't forget to add a respective comment for such a case. Just local variables should have done as well I must admit... ;-)